# Georeferencing raster image in JavaScript

Tags: raster, javascript, georeferencing, mapbox, react

I was wondering if it is possible to georeference raster image using some kind of JavaScript lib or external API or other kind of service. My project is written in React with Mapbox GL JS. I wanted to provide an oportunity to georeference image without using external apps like QGIS. Is it possible? Can you give me some ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.davidrumsey.com/ has had on-line georeferencing for years. I have no idea how it's done. I used it for a while until I found QGIS.

Here's a link to a page open to georeferencing. I'm logged in so the link may not work, but one can create an account. Although I did that five years ago at least.

[https://www.davidrumsey.com/luna/servlet/detail/RUMSEY~8~1~246077~5514735:Plate-1,-Los-Angeles,-California-?sort=pub_list_no_initialsort%2Cpub_date%2Cpub_list_no%2Cseries_no&qvq=q:baist;sort:pub_list_no_initialsort%2Cpub_date%2Cpub_list_no%2Cseries_no;lc:RUMSEY~8~1&mi=4&trs=63](https://www.davidrumsey.com/luna/servlet/detail/RUMSEY%7E8%7E1%7E246077%7E5514735:Plate-1,-Los-Angeles,-California-?sort=pub_list_no_initialsort%2Cpub_date%2Cpub_list_no%2Cseries_no&qvq=q:baist;sort:pub_list_no_initialsort%2Cpub_date%2Cpub_list_no%2Cseries_no;lc:RUMSEY%7E8%7E1&mi=4&trs=63)

PS I just saw your comment. I'm just saying it can be done. Maybe Ramsey can help you. From their about page: [Georeferencer v4](https://www.georeferencer.com/) software and hosting by [Klokan Technologies](https://www.klokantech.com/)

Comment: The is one problem to your solution. I have to do the georeferencing from inside of the React app. That's why I'm looking for some kind of JS lib or external API service (It doesn't have to be free of charge). QGIS is one of the best GIS solutions out there, but we are writing our own web app, so I'm looking for possible solutions. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this georeferencing widget used in ArcGIS Javascript API apps. Source code is linked in their Github, it might give you some ideas.
https://github.com/DCGIS/esri-webappbuilder-widget-georeferencing